# Считывание последних 10 строк текстового файла, неопределенного размера

Tags: файлы, c#

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как считать 10 строк текстового файла, неопределенного размера?

Comment: @Sergey4590, да в общем-то так же, как и на Java, о чем Вы уже спрашивали.

А что, там не получилось?

Comment: Просто я в данный момент работаю с java. Но больше и лучше я знаю C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если Вам нужно решать эту задачу "постоянно", то наиболее правильный способ - сделать "индекс". То есть, пробегаем по файлу "побайтно" (но только не нужно читать по байту - читайте кусками по 4-8 кб) и запоминайте позиции перевода строк (можно запоминать позиции начала новой строки) и записывайте это в файл (можно писать потоком, по 4 или 8 байт на позицию (в зависимости от того, чем пользуетесь для чтения файла)).

Такой файл будет генерировать по скорости пропорционально размеру.

После генерации подобного файла задача стает тривиальной - ищете функцию/метод seek (или аналоги), рассчитываете нужную позицию, позиционируетесь и читаете как обычно.

Если этот файл дописывается, то файл индекса обновить очень легко, нужно только взять последнюю доступную позицию и пробежать до конца файла.

---

Более сложный способ следующий. Исходим из того, что длина строки обычно символов 80 (у Вас это может быть совсем другое). Считываем самый последний блок размером не менее 80 * 10 = 800 символов (логично читать 4 кб). Это легко сделать , если вначале спозиционировать с помощью seek. Этот блок доступными средствами разбивается на строки (помните, что первая строка скорее всего будет неполная!). Если строк больше 10 - вырезаем последние, если нет - то вычитываем ещё один блок, который находиться перед ним, склеиваем и снова парсим. Но я уверен, что блока в 8 кб в большинстве случаев должно хватить на "10 последних строк".

Пара слов о реализации. Для начала нужен метод [seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx). У него два параметра - позиция и "метод отсчета". "метод отсчета" может иметь три значения "от начала файла", "от текущей позиции" и "от конца файла" (`SeekOrigin.End`). Поэтому, написав что то в виде:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\alphabet.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    fs.Seek(-8*1024, SeekOrigin.End); // минус - так как отсчет от конца
    fs.read... // а здесь можно просто читать строки до конца файла, правда первую стоит выбросить - она скорее всего будет "с середины".
}
```

P.S. я не большой специалист в шарпах, поэтому код могу писать с ошибками.

Comment: Извините, а вы не могли бы написать как это будет выглядеть на java, если он вам больше знаком? Т. е. как поделить файл на блоки и вывести последний блок на экран?

Comment: Разберитесь с [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Правда там метод seek немного обрезан, но там есть метод length. Поэтому:

    f.seek(f.length() - 8*1024);
    f.readLine(); // just skip
    while (!f.eof()) { // я знаю, там нет eof, но это демо
      String s = f.readLine();
      // добавить s в список.
    }
    f.close();
    // это условно, я думаю, Вы напишете лучше алгоритм.
    while (длина списка больше 10) {
      удалить первую строку списка();
    }

Comment: я немного по-другому сделал,но благодаря Вашей помощи заработало!Большое Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

(Вынес из комментариев)

Вариация ответа [[@IronVbif](/users/443/ironvbif)](/users/443/ironvbif), `O(размер файла)` по времени и `O(количество интересующих строк)` по памяти:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Last<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
    {
        using(var it = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            var buffer = new Queue<T>();

            while (buffer.Count < n && it.MoveNext())
                buffer.Enqueue(it.Current);

            while (it.MoveNext())
            {
                buffer.Dequeue();
                buffer.Enqueue(it.Current);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}

//...
var last10 = File.ReadLines("test.txt").Last(10).ToList();
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/YFmcRL

Если вам нужна скорость `O(количество интересующих строк)` (например, если файл очень большой), вам придётся проводить ручной парсинг: читайте файл *с конца*, подсчитывая символы конца строк. Не забудьте, что последняя строка может быть и без такого символа.

Comment: какие то нули странные в ответе.

Comment: @KoVadim: это вы об [асимптотике](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) времени выполнения и расхода памяти?

Comment: странное обозначение сложности. (я не по поводу буквы О. просто не видел, что бы в скобках так писали). Написали бы просто, что все ваши решение имеют линейную сложность от размера файла. На больших файлах сложность от кол-ва строк будет близка к сложности от размера в байтах.

Реализация циклического буфера чудесная. Вот если к этому решению добавить позиционирование на предполагаемую позицию, то будет неплохо.

Comment: Вариация на вариацию =) http://ideone.com/N1NMCJ

Comment: @KoVadim: Вы имеете в виду, позиционирование внутри файла? Это с таким подходом не выйдет, т.к. `ReadLines` скрывает «внутренности» реализации чтения. (Можно, конечно, заимплементировать `ReadLinesBackwards`.) Или вы имеете в виду номер строки?

Comment: а чем номера строк помогут. Я имел конечно же ввиду классическое позиционирование.

Вот из за таких абстракций и страдаем.

Comment: @KoVadim: Почему же страдаем? В C# есть и стандартный доступ к файлу, если хочется возится с номерами байт. Обычно текстовый файл нужно всё равно читать весь построчно (и записывать тоже весь, т.к. при редактировании строки позиции последующих строк в файле «слетают»), поэтому абстракция в виде `IEnumerable<string>` довольно полезна. Но для _оптимального_ решения задачи ТС нужна более низкоуровневая абстракция.

Comment: страдаем - потому что многие программисты используют подобные абстракции, где это не нужно. А оно жутко тормозит. Чего только стоит один из сервис паков к студии (кажеться к 2005), который устанавливался более 3 часов - он распаковывал каждый файл из большого архива и проверял его чексумму место того, что бы распаковать все сразу и проверить.

Comment: Боюсь, что и чексумма проверялась с целью понять, менять ли файл (если чексумма не совпадает, то менять) на новый :)

Answer (score 0):

Linq вариант:

```
var strs = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").Reverse().Take(10).Reverse().ToList();
```

Comment: если размер файла пару гигов - это доставит массу удовольствия:)

Comment: Ну тогда `File.ReadLines`: ненужные строки не будут храниться в памяти.

Comment: Reverse() делает копию

Comment: @IronVbif: Хм, и правда. Тогда так: http://ideone.com/YFmcRL